# Graph API for 365 Teams Chats throttled to 20 messages per chat

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In the wake of the new beta API for it, I have written a script that exports Teams one to one chats to a text file. This is so that, after migrating to a new tenant, my users can have their chat history in some place. After finishing the code and trying it on my first user, I found that I can only pull the most recent 20 messages per chat.

Here is the API command I am using: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/chatmessage-list.md

Is there any way to turn off throttling, or is there some step I am missing so that I can export *all* chat messages? I'm new to the Graph API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not causing because of throttling issue.

Graph API implements paging for certain API. For [List chat messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) API, **20** message is the limit currently. The API response has *"@odata.nextLink"* property with the link to fetch next 20 messages.

**Sample Response**

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/LongUrlShort/messages",
"@odata.count": 20,
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/LongUrlhSort",
```

So you need to handle it while calling the API. You can make the API call in loop and get all the records.

Comment: on powershell, you can do it with ```get-mgchatmessage -pagesize 50 -all```. Putting it here since this is the top result for this issue regardless of language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query parameter `?top=30` to get the top 30 messages. There is no documentation on this.

Here is the reference URL.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/ms-teams-graph-api-number-of-messages-returned-by-get-messages/m-p/819565

In my case, I found that it also has a limit of 50.

i.e.

```
?top=50
```